# convert a string value into regular date in AIX UNIX

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp, aix

I am passing a Julian date value as argument in my UNX script. Based on the date value it gets converted to regular date. However the constraint is that currently I am able to convert it only for current or previous date. following is my code

```
    PARAM_NAME=$1
PARAM_VALUE=$2 //where Julian date is passed

if [[  $PARAM_NAME == 'LOANS_BATCH_CONTROL_PS.ISLFILE_PROCESSING_DATE' && $PARAM_VALUE == `TZ=aaa24 date +%y%j` ]]; then
date_replace_string=`TZ=aaa24 date +%m%d%Y`
PARAM_VALUE=$date_replace_string
```

I wondered if there is anyway where I could take this paramter_value with any date value(julian date: eg. 16074) and convert it to a regular date and not just current day date or previous day date

Comment: Given your "julian" date of 16074, what should be the Gregorian "YYYY-mm-dd" date? http://aa.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/aa_jdconv.pl?form=2&jd=16074 suggests the Gregorian date is in the year 4669 BC

Comment: The Gregorian date for 16074 is 2016-03-14. Essentially 16 stands for year 2016 while 074 is the 74th day of this year.

Comment: That's definitely not a [Julian date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know AIX that well. If your Perl distribution is relatively up-to-date, you can do:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -sle '
    $t = Time::Piece->strptime($date,"%y%j"); 
    print $t->strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
' -- -date="16074"
```

```
2016-03-14
```

[Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) is a core Perl module, but I don't recall which perl version introduced it.

Answer (score 1):

[Dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) can do that:

```
$ dateconv -i '%y%D' 16074 -f '%Y-%m-%d'
2016-03-14
```

where `%D` is the day-of-year count.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the tool(s).

Answer (score 0):

You could do the maths with GNU-date, sg. like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE=gdate

jul7_to_std () {
    local Y=${1%???}
    local j=${1#????}
    local j_1=$(expr $j - 1)
    local jan1=${Y}0101
    $DATE '+%Y%m%d' -d "$jan1 +$j_1 days"
}

jul5_to_std () {
    jul7_to_std 20$1
}

jul7_plus () {
    local dstd="$(jul7_to_std $1)"
    local dtmp="$dstd"
    if [ $2 -gt 0 ]; then
        dtmp=$($DATE '+%Y%m%d' -d "$dstd +$2 days")
    elif [ $2 -lt 0 ]; then
        dtmp=$($DATE '+%Y%m%d' -d "$dstd $2 days")
    fi
    $DATE '+%Y%j' -d "$dtmp"
}

jul5_plus () {
    local tmp="$(jul7_plus "20$1" "$2")"
    echo "${tmp#??}"
}

jul5_plus 16001  365
jul5_plus 15123    1
jul5_plus 16100 -200
```

Comment: I suspect you'll need `#!/bin/bash` not `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: I suggest avoiding bash-specific features, especially on AIX