# Replace value of a specific column from a file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have file whose size is approx 1 GB and that file has a data in below format .

```
A|CD|44123|0|0
B|CD|44124|0|0
C|CD|44125|0|0
D|CD|44126|0|0
E|CD|44127|0|0
F|CD|44128|0|0
J|CD|44129|0|0
I|CD|44130|0|0
```

In this file I have to replace the third column value from a value which i will get after conversion . For which i have to open this file and then read the file and replace it . This process is taking around 5 hours .Below is the code which i am using

```
cat $FILE_NAME |\
while read REC
do
  DATE=`echo "$REC" | cut -d\| -f3`
  DATE_NEW=`$UTIL $DATE | head -1 |cut -d" " -f12`
  RECORD="$DATE_NEW,"
  echo "$RECORD" >> $New_File
done
```

Is there a way we can make this more better and fast.

Desired output will be like this where `DATE_NEW` value will be placed on each 3rd column DATE_NEW value will be the converted value which I will get from this

```
DATE_NEW=`$UTIL $DATE | head -1 |cut -d" " -f12`

A|CD|10/20/2020|0|0
B|CD|10/25/2020|0|0
C|CD|10/25/2020|0|0
D|CD|10/25/2020|0|0
E|CD|11/15/2020|0|0
F|CD|11/14/2020|0|0
J|CD|11/16/2020|0|0
I|CD|11/17/2020|0|0
```

After the comment from @Sundeep Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?  I wrote the logic in Perl and from 5-7 hours processing time in Perl it took 99 Seconds to get the job done.

Comment: Do you want to replace 3rd column in every record?

Comment: See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for answers to `This process is taking around 5 hours`

Comment: I have updated the question with details

Comment: @Sundeep $UTIL a binary which i will run to convert 44129 Julian date in dd/mm/yy format .

Comment: Add desired output for 44123 to 44130 to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus updated the desired output

Comment: as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/36039098, I get `02/05/2044` for `44123`..

Comment: @Sundeep that is not correct .

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
awk -v cmd="Cmd2GetNEWDATE" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{cmd|getline v;close(cmd)}$3=v' file
```